# Plotting iterations of k-means in R

Tags: r, k-means

I found this code from [Rentrop](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3301344/rentrop) on an answer to a different k-means plotting questions but was wondering why this only plots two iterations on any given dataset. Is there a way to generalize it to stop plotting when it converges instead of just stopping after two iterations?

```
set.seed(1337)
df = iris[,1:2]


dfCluster<-kmeans(df,centers=3, iter.max = 1)
  plot(df[,1], df[,2], col=dfCluster$cluster,pch=19,cex=2, main="iter 1")
  points(dfCluster$centers,col=1:5,pch=3,cex=3,lwd=3)

max_iter = 10

for (i in 2:max_iter){
  tryCatch({
    dfCluster <- kmeans(df,centers = dfCluster$centers, iter.max = 1)
    done <- TRUE
  }, 
  warning=function(w) {done <- FALSE})
  plot(df[,1], df[,2], col=dfCluster$cluster,pch=19,cex=2, main=paste("iter",i))
  points(dfCluster$centers,col=1:5,pch=3,cex=3,lwd=3)
  if(done) break
}
```

Comment: Nope. If you use kmeans.ani on the same data it takes 8 iterations. Changing the data takes the same number of iterations.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to modify the existing code as little as possible, then reverse the TRUE/FALSE in `tryCatch`:

```
tryCatch({
dfCluster <- kmeans(df,centers = dfCluster$centers, iter.max = 1)
done <- FALSE #was TRUE
}, 
warning=function(w) {done <- TRUE}) #was FALSE
```

However, this code plots however many plots are in `max_iter` regardless of whether kmeans converges in 2 iterations or 20.  Here's my re-write:

```
# data
set.seed(1234)
df = iris[ , 1:2]

# functions for plotting
myplot <- function(out, i) {
    plot(df[,1], df[,2], pch=20, main=paste("iter",i),
         col=scales::alpha(out$cluster, "0.5"))
}

mypoints <- function(out) {
    points(out$centers, col=1:3, pch=3, cex=2, lwd=3)
}

# number of plots = min(user-specified iters, iters until convergence)
actual_iters <- kmeans(df, centers=3)$iter
max_iter = 10
N <- min(max_iter, actual_iters)

# initial kmeans
out <- kmeans(df, centers=3, iter.max=1)
myplot(out,1)
mypoints(out)

# loop through next iters of kmeans
for (i in 2:N){
    out <- kmeans(df, centers=out$centers, iter.max=1)
    myplot(out,i)
    mypoints(out)
}
```